# Proper word for last tooth in row

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

All humans have two rows of teeth. What is proper word for teeth at the ends of the tooth rows?

"Last tooth" sounds strange. As if a person has lost all teeth except one.
"Tooth at the end" - too long.
Is there one unambiguous adjective for such teeth?

Answer (score 1):

In English, we describe teeth in terms of how far forward or backward they are in the mouth.

We have two "front teeth" in each row. The opposite of these would be the "**furthest back teeth**". The group of teeth at the back of the mouth also have a technical name, *molars.* For many adult humans, the furthest back molars are the *third molars,* which are commonly called "[wisdom teeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom_tooth)". Many others have these teeth extracted at some point (or lack them for other reasons), leaving the *second molars* as the teeth furthest back in the mouth.

Comment: Though it's worth noting that I've never heard anyone other than my dentist and his staff use the term "third/second molar". :D

Comment: "Molar" or "third molar" is a type of a tooth. I need common word that means last tooth in the row regardless of its type. For example a person does not have all upper left molars.

Comment: "furthest back teeth" is also long. Are really such words common and understandable?

Comment: @Andrey Epifantsev, there is not always a single proper noun for everything you wish to describe  in the English language, or if there is on it is so archaic that most people will not know it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a wisdom tooth in a row of teeth, you can call the tooth at the end  either a back tooth or a wisdom tooth. If you don't have a wisdom tooth, you can call it a back tooth.

Answer (score 1):

The back set of large teeth are called

> molars

and the furthest back is called your

> wisdom teeth

but one would already need to know this to understand.

I believe you are referring to #8 or #9 in the diagram.

[image]